# How to make sure only certain-purpose-functions are passed in only in a Scala Method

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I was reading some material on Scala, where I came across this method signature:

```
def calculateStateTax(f: Double => Double, personsIncome: Double): Double = ...
```

and I was wondering, if we had functions that calculate tax for different states, how would we make sure that the function which is passed in is used to calculate state tax and that only? i.e. it's not some other operation on a Double. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just wrap it in `case class Tax(value: Double)`, then proceed to read how floating point numbers aren't good for money ops, so change to `case class Tax(value: BigDecimal)`, and voila, pop open the champagne.

Comment: Thanks Flavian for taking time to answer

Comment: Can we do something using type keyword?

Comment: You could but it would be a small smell.

Answer (score 0):

It is more on the modeling side, you can wrap the Double into case class Tax(money: Double) then on the method signature you will have:

```
def calculateStateTax(f: Tax => Double, personsIncome: Double): Double = ...
```

Then you just need to trust that the author of the `f` method your using is doing it right or you can always check the method call.

Comment: Thanks Leo for answering.